# URL on a landing page and URL after logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, web

Why are  a landing page and a page after user logs in same on most websites? For example, on Facebook the landing page url is https://www.facebook.com. After you logs into FB you are redirected to Home but same url as above: https://www.facebook.com.

Does it mean Facebook uses the same file (e.g. index.html/index.php) for the landing page and the the page after user logs in?

Thanks!

Comment: emm, I havn't worked for Facebook yet, still considering their offer,lol, but I think it's quite common using same file/page for home/login/landingpage, its quite easy to implement

Comment: but if you put everything into 1 file, it's gonna be quite messy:( Do you know any tutorials about how to manage everything into 1 file?

Comment: depends on your server site language, but be short, it;s not complex, what  language you use for server side?

Comment: I've been using PHP!

Comment: First of all you need to understand that there is not necessarily a direct connection between URLs and “files” …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webserver can serve different content based on many factors; cookies in this case. The URL you see in the bar doesn't have to correlate the same path on some server - the application can dynamically accept or reject any path (it's just a string). In PHP, you can do this with a [front controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/) which is pattern used by many frameworks like Symphony and Laravel.

As for why Facebook does this, they probably just think it looks better that way.